# Serverless does not create SQS events

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to make serverless create a trigger to fire whenever an object queues. But it does not create and also does not fire any errors.

My serverless.yml:
I did according to the documentation (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs/)

```js
service: lambda-messages

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 256
  iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
     - sqs:SendMessage
     - sqs:ReceiveMessage
     - sqs:DeleteMessage
     - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
     Resource: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:074601456889:messages

functions:
  addMessages:
    timeout: 10
    handler: handler.addMessages
    events:
     - http:
         path: v1/chat/addMessages
         method: post

  receiveMessage:
    timeout: 10
    handler: handler.receiveMessage
    reservedConcurrency: 10
    events:
     - sqs:
       arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:074601456889:messages
       batchSize: 2
```

But it does not create

[Image console lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg6QS.png)

Comment: Does the SQS queue already exist in the account? or are you trying to create it in this project?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the indentation in your YAML file, just add two spaces in front of "arn" and "batchSize"

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Add 2 spaces on the sqs. Added a picture for good measure!

Answer (score -1):

You have to create queue by yourself, as mentioned in [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs/).
Because serverless won't create SQS for you, it can only put listener on already existing queue.
You can find how to do it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-create-queue.html).
Serverless don't create SQS for you because there is two types of queues available to choose according to your needs. It's up to you to choose the queue type, then create it and only after this serverless will find your queue and attach worker.

Comment: But I do not want to create the queue. I want to add events that trigger lambda via serverless.

Comment: @brindedsbrindeds2, according to your configuration in `serverless.yml`, you're trying to listen sqs events. If you want to trigger function by event, take a look at cloud watch events.  https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-event/

Comment: @brindedsbrindeds2 or look at this link https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/ in section `events`. There is examples for events, which you can trigger lambda by

Comment: Serverless will create the SQS Queue if you add it to the `Resources` section and reference it in `events` and `iamRoleStatements` properties.