# AWS Serverless : SQS Lambda trigger not getting created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless framework and trying to create SQS triggers for lambda function.

The SQS Queue is already created using another serverless template.

When I execute the serverless deploy command, there are no errors, but the SQS trigger is also **not** created.

Here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: cloudformation-demo

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  CONNECT_DEVICE_SQS_ROLE_NAME: SqSConnectRole
  CONNECT_DEVICE_SQS_QUEUE_NAME: connectDeviceSQSDemo1


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1


package:
 individually: true
 exclude:
   - ./**

functions:
   lambdaenvinfo:
    handler: bin/handlers/lambdaenvinfo
    timeout: 900
    package:
     exclude:
        - "**/**"
     include:
       - ./bin/handlers/lambdaenvinfo
     events:
      - sqs:
         arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:672851574246:connectDeviceSQSDemo
         batchSize: 1
         enabled: true
```

I also referred to this thread, and tried to add required spaces.

[Serverless does not create SQS events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974560/serverless-does-not-create-sqs-events)

Any solutions to this problem?
It's surprising to see serverless doesn't display any errors.

Comment: Are you using the correct event in your Go function's Lambda handler? Or do you not see any event at all in the Lambda Management Console for this function? I do not have experience with the Serverless framework, but believe it isn't much different from the official library and the Serverless Application Model https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go. Is your function deployed to us-east-1?

Comment: @Dattatray Not sure if it's an issue, but I don't believe `enabled: true` is actually required here. Also, Serverless Framework is just a way of interacting with ClodFormation, so probably worth checking the stack out and see exactly what has happened there.

Comment: I don't see any event trigger at all in the Lambda management console. Yes the lambda function is deployed in US-east-1

Comment: But have you checked what was created in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue, the lambda SQS triggers are getting created now.

Main Problems -

1. Indentation of the serverless.yml file needs to be correct ( in this case, serverless doesn't give any errors)

( Observe the spaces before sqs, events, include, exclude, in the below serverless yml file )

2. The format to specify the event trigger for Lambda in case of SQs is bit different.

> sqs: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:672851574246:connectDeviceSQSDemo

I have modified the serverless.yml file ( it's working now)

```
service: cloudformation-demo

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  CONNECT_DEVICE_SQS_ROLE_NAME: SqSConnectRole
  CONNECT_DEVICE_SQS_QUEUE_NAME: connectDeviceSQSDemo1


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1


package:
 individually: true
 exclude:
   - ./**

functions:
  lambdaenvinfo:
    handler: bin/handlers/lambdaenvinfo
    timeout: 30
    package:
      exclude:
        - "**/**"
      include:
       - ./bin/handlers/lambdaenvinfo
    events:
       - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:672851574246:connectDeviceSQSDemo
```